# Anyone knows the difference between visual studio 2012 VS visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there anyone who can better explain the visual studio 2012 and visual studio 2010  Features?

Comment: differences* - there are much more than one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A part from this can anyone have a better explaination.?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of differences. The best place to start is with the "What's New in Visual Studio 2012" page which you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I intiate with the given link but its not the exact which i looking for.Do you have any other link .

Comment: You didn't have that link when I posted this. We must have posted this at the same time as the time stamp indicates. Once of the key differences is that you can create Windows Store (win 8) apps in VS2012 but not in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot of differences! Either you need to ask for an aspect specifically or I'll just tell you "they look different, like, alot, but not soo much". But in all seriousness, there is a [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to consult about the new features of Visual Studio 2012.

Additionally, the answer is dependent on the version you choose (Express, Professional, Ultimate...).

If you are asking for a feature matrix, I only know of [this](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs) one comparing Pro, Ultimate and Premium, but regarding VS2013 and [this](http://www.vlaquest.com/2013/04/visual-studio-2012-express-editions-feature-matrix/) comparing the Express versions of VS2012.